# Yii Relation data issue with HasMany

Tags: php, yii

Currently we have two tables.
Locations and Addresses

Locations are a 1 to many relation to addresses on addresses.location_id.

We are trying to output all addresses related to a specific location in the cgridview:

**admin.php**

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'locations-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$location->search(),
    'filter'=>$location,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'name',
        array(
            'name' => 'address',
            'value' => 'implode("<br>",CHtml::listData($data->addresses(),"id","address"))',
            'filter' => CHtml::activeTextField($location, 'address'),
            'type' => 'html',
        ),/**/  
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

**model (locations.php)**

```
public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->together = true;
        $criteria->with = array('addresses');
        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
        $criteria->compare('addresses.address',$this->address,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

Is there a better way of going about getting the address data rather then imploding the $data->addresses function?

Comment: `Currently we have two databases.` Perhaps you mean `tables` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Just corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a getter method to your `Locations` model.

```
public function getAddressNames($separator='<br>')
{
    $names = array();
    foreach($this->adresses as $address) {
        $names[] = $address->address;
    }
    return implode($separator, $names);
}
```

Then you can use `addressNames` like a regular attribute in your gridview.